# The number of keys specified in the URI does not match number of key properties for the resource 'microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are trying to use Graph APIs for Bookings application. In fact, we are customizing
the C# code from the microsoft sample :

https://microsoft.github.io/bookings-samples/

We have the application registration and all the permissions configured in Azure.
Using the BookingsSampleNativeConsole, we are able to query the graphService.BookingBusinesses
as shown below.

var graphService = new GraphService(GraphService.ServiceRoot,
() => authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader());

Unfortunately none of the other entities gets populated. So we are using the following to query the appointments:

```
Uri appointUri = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/{id}/appointments");
  
var appointParams = new UriOperationParameter[]
 {
            new UriOperationParameter("start", "2020-08-01T00:00:00Z"),
            new UriOperationParameter("end", "2020-08-31T00:00:00Z")
        };
```

var resp = graphService.Execute(appointUri, "GET", appointParams);

But this call returns :

An error occurred while processing this request. --->
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException:

```
{
  "error": 
   {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The number of keys specified in the URI does not match number of key properties for the resource 'microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment'."
   }
}
```

Any idea what we are missing or wrong with appointParams ?
Thanks in advance.

(2)Graph APIs for Bookings has been in beta for quite sometime now. Any idea
when is the probable release date for version 1.0 ?

Ajit19